# Out of 100%, if 52% of the population is type X, and 51% type Y...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Out of 100%, if 52% of the population is type X, and 51% type Y but every single type Y person also has a second type X then how many type X people (without type Y) are there?

Am I correct to say that it is 52%-51%=1% (1)

Or is the correct answer 1-51/52=1.923% (2)

Also, I essentially don't really know the difference between (1) and (2). If we put this into English words, exactly what are these two equations doing?

Comment: Take a concrete example: suppose there are 100 people. Write down a Venn diagram if it helps you. How many of those 100 people have type X without type Y?

Comment: Well, 1 person I assume.  So the answer should be 1%.  But does (2) represent anything meaningful? Or no

Comment: The second represents the proportion of **Type Y people** who are not of Type X.  But the question asks for the proportion of the overall population which is of Type Y but not X.